# Publish SPA on server

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, single-page-application

I am currently working on a single page web application. The frontend communicates with backend services, which in turn have database connections. On my own linux server I want to "publish" the SPA. For the local development I used Docker. On my server I wanted to use Docker as well. For deployment I use Jenkins (also via Docker). Now, during the Jenkins build, I get the error "docker: command not found" during the "docker run" command. According to research, the solution is that I should install docker on top of Jenkins. This sounds a bit weird to me. Am I on the right way here? What is the best way to build the deployment pipeline?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I think there is a lot more to unpack here. The solution is what you say, installing docker is required to use docker. Where/how to use docker is entirely driven by your infrastructure and how jenkins is deployed and run. Are there jenkins agents? Then install docker there. If not, install the engine on jenkins main. Is jenkins already running in docker? Then docker-in-docker solution is needed. Without much other context, the solution is to install docker engine if you need to build docker images in pipeline.

Comment: Hello, jenkins is running in Docker. But I can install it outside (manually) if it is the better way. Is it better not to run jenkins in Docker?

Comment: Either way are valid, but in terms of best practice and supportability, you probably want any build tools running in an agent container, so as to not adjust the primary jenkins service. Running jenkins in a container is fine.

Comment: this is not a place where people will do your homework on your behalf. Instead, start doing, if you face issue, come here

Comment: Look at my toy project here: https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment

It has all relevant links to get you started. Key point you're missing is you need to push images from Jenkins to some image registry, and then on your server it should pull images from that registry. To begin with this could be as simple as a cron job on a single VM.

Comment: Hey @taleodor, thanks for your link! It looks very great!